# How do you balance action and introspection in a story?

Tags: creative-writing, story

In my opinion, a story needs both action and introspection to be engaging, but finding the right balance can be tricky. Too much action can make a story feel really shallow, while too much introspection can slow the pace and bore my readers. By introspection, I mean a character's inner thought. You want your characters to think about what they did and what they are to add depth. How do you balance them in a story?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you balance them will depend on the kind of story you want to write. Romance for women has a lot of "interiority", while action books are more focussed on what people do. There is no general ideal balance. Different readers like different things, and the best guide is what other writers do in the genre you are writing. So read some books with a writer's eye and see how it is conventionally done.

Or just write your story however you like to write it and let it find the readers that like the way you write.